# JSpinner date/time format in java netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jspinner

I want to create a spinner that has date/time in the format yyyy/mm/dd hh/mm/ss. I have netbeans and I'm using its GUI to create the spinner. I can select the date model which shows the date and time on the spinner, however its not in the format i want.

How can i change the format using the netbeans GUI on the spinner?

Comment: The [JSpinner Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) shows you how to create custom spinner models and editors. If you've not studied it yet, you will want to give it a look.

Comment: [`JCalendar`](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/) is a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

declare the following

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public SimpleDateFormat yourDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
```